# object not confirming protocol does not give any warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a class "ABC" and its method which returns non autoreleases object of that class.

```
@interface ABC:NSObject
+(ABC *)aClassMethodReturnsObjectWhichNotAutoreleased;
@end  

@implementation ABC
+(ABC *)aClassMethodReturnsObjectWhichNotAutoreleased{
   ABC *a = [[ABC alloc]init];
   return a;
}
@end
```

If I have a protocol Foo.

```
@Protocol Foo
@required
-(void)abc;
@end
```

My ABC class is "not" confirming Foo protocols.

1st call

```
id<Foo> obj = [ABC aClassMethodReturnsObjectWhichNotAutoreleased]; //show warning
```

It shows warning "Non Compatible pointers.." thats good.Abc did not confirm protocol Foo

BUT
2nd call

```
id<Foo> obj = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"def",nil]; // It will "not" show warning as it will return autorelease object.NSArray don't confirm protocol Foo
```

In first call compiler gives warning and in second call compiler is not giving any warning.I think that is because i am not returning autorelease object.

Why is compiler not giving warning in 2nd call as NSArray is also not confirming FOO
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the return value is a specific type so the compiler can verify the assignment.

In the second example, the `NSArray arrayWithObjects:` method has a return type of `id`. You can assign an object of type `id` to a variable of any type. The compiler has no way to verify that what you are doing is truly correct or not.

This issue has nothing to do with autoreleased objects. It's all about the data types. `id` is a kind of catch-all type that can be anything.

Comment: Shouldn't it still check for protocol conformance though, since he has `id <Foo> obj =`?

Comment: No. You can assign an object of type `id` to a variable of ANY object type. No checking is done by the compiler.